# "revealed dependencies not in the API" during bundle install

Tags: ruby, bundler

Getting this error during bundle install with jruby

"Downloading tzinfo-data-1.2013.4 revealed dependencies not in the API or the
lockfile (tzinfo (>= 1.0.0))."

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this error by downgrading bundler from 1.15.4 to 1.12.5